# Train keras model with different inputs which go through exact same keras model?

Tags: keras, tensor

In a current project, I need to get an exact copy of a keras model, which not only has the same architecture, but the exact same weights of the original model. Eventually, I want to use both instances, the original and the copy, in the training of the network. The "complicated" thing for me about this is, that I need to have this copy before training.

The backround is the following: I want to minimize the energy distance (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Energy_distance) of a random variable Y and a transformed random variable X = g(Z). Now in order to minimize the energy distance, I not only need to minimize ||Y - g(Z)|| but also ||g(Z) - g(Z')||, where Z' is a independent copy of Z. Now the transformation g is done by the neural net and it has to be the same for g(Z) and g(Z').

Here is an example code to maybe explain the idea a little better: I initialize two keras models and try to assign the weights from the first model `model` to `model_copy`, whoever in the next step, the model compilation, I can only train the models individually. I want to minimize it kind of jointly.

```
Inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape = (500, 8,), dtype = tf.float32)
l1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation = "relu")(Inputs)
l2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(5)(l1)

Inputs_copy = tf.keras.Input(shape = (500, 8,), dtype = tf.float32)
l1_copy = tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation = "relu")(Inputs_copy)
l2_copy = tf.keras.layers.Dense(5)(l1_copy)
# here I want to tranfer the weights of l2 to l2_copy

model = tf.keras.Model(Inputs, l2)
model_copy = tf.keras.Model(Inputs_copy, l2_copy)

model.layers[1].get_weights()[0]
model_copy.layers[1].set_weights(model_copy.layers[1].get_weights())
```

I experimented with `get.weights()` and `set_weights` but this does not seem to work (I guess that the reason is, that the weights are not initialized/trained yet).

Can anybody help with this problem? How can I deal with this problem of having two independent inputs that have to go through the same model and this same model has to be trained. I hope it has become somewhat clear what the question is. Thankful for any comments!

I tried `get.weights` and `set_weights` but then I end up with two individual models that I cannot train jointly. Taking both inputs together as one input results in the Inputs having different weights.